# Euler equation first integral of $f^* = (y-\lambda)\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ is $\frac{y-\lambda}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=A$?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm looking at this isoperimetric problem with
$$I = \int_{0}^a{y\sqrt{1+y'^2}}dx $$
subject to the constraint 
$$J = \int_{0}^a{y\sqrt{1+y'^2}}dx = l $$
Using Lagrange multipliers so 
$$I^* = I-\lambda J = \int_{0}^a{(y-\lambda)\sqrt{1+y'^2}}dx = min$$
$$y(0)=y(a)=0$$
And the book is saying that since $f^*=(y-\lambda)\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ doesn't contain any explicit x dependence, the Euler equation has the first integral
$$\frac{y-\lambda}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=A$$

I'm not able to produce this result. The Euler equation is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'})=0$, and integrating it should give
$$\int{\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)\right]dx}=x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)=x\sqrt{1+y'^2}-\frac{(y-\lambda)(y')}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=A$$

Can somebody show me what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): There seems to be a $y$ too many in OP's second integral.

Comment: which book are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your last integration is that $\partial f/\partial y$ is still a function of $x$, so you can't just integrate it as if it's constant.

The book is probably alluding to the Beltrami identity, which says that if $\partial f/\partial x=0$ (no explicit $x$-dependence),
$$ f- y' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} $$
is constant (that is, independent of $x$) for a $y$ satisfying the Euler–Lagrange equation. (This is the obscure first integral: other special cases have more obvious ones, like $\partial f /\partial y=0$ means that $\partial f/\partial y'$ is constant.) One can verify this easily enough:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left( f- y' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + y'' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} - y'' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} - y' \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \\
= 0 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - y' \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \right)y' = 0. $$

Using this then gives
$$ A = (y-\lambda)\sqrt{1+y'^2} - y'(y-\lambda)\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} = \frac{y-\lambda}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}. $$